# How is Kubernetes RBAC Actually Enforced for Service Accounts?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

We're trying to create different kuberentes secrets and offer access to specific secrets through specific service accounts that are assigned to pods. For example:

Secrets

```
- User-Service-Secret
- Transaction-Service-Secret
```

Service Account

```
- User-Service
- Transaction-Service
```

Pods

```
- User-Service-Pod
- Transaction-Service-Pod
```

The idea is to restrict access to `User-Service-Secret`secret to `User-Service` service account that is assign to `User-Service-Pod`. So we can set this all up with the relevant kuberentes resources (i.e. ServiceAccount, Role, RoleBinding), but we realize that this may not be actually enforced, because `Transaction-Service-Pod` can just as easily read the `User-Service-Secret` secret when Pod starts up, even though the service account its assign to doesn't have `get` permission to the `User-Service-Secret`.

How do we actually enforce the RBAC system?

FYI we are using EKS

Answer (score 2):

First it is important to distinguish between API access to the secret and consuming the secret as an environment variable or a mounted volume.

TLDR:

- RBAC controls who can access a secret (or any other resource) using K8s API requests.
- Namespaces or the service account's `secrets` attribute control if a pod can consume a secret as an environment variable or through a volume mount.

## API access

RBAC is used to control if an identity (in your example the service account) is allowed to access a resource via the K8s API. You control this by creating a RoleBinding (namespaced) or a ClusterRoleBinding (cluster-wide) that binds an identity to a Role (namespaced) or a ClusterRole (not-namespaced) to your identity (service account). Then, when you assign the service account to a pod by setting the `serviceAccountName` attribute, running kubectl get secret in that pod or the equivalent method from one of the client libraries would mean you have credentials available to make the API request.

## Consuming Secrets

This however is independent of configuring the pod to consume the secret as an environment variable or a volume mount. If the container spec in a pod spec references the secret it is made available inside that container. Note, per container, not per pod. You can limit what secret a pod can mount by having the pods in different namespaces, because a pod can only refer to a secret in the same namespace. Additionally, you can use the service account's `secrets` attribute, to limit what secrets a pod with thet service account can refer to.

```
$ kubectl explain sa.secrets
KIND:     ServiceAccount
VERSION:  v1

RESOURCE: secrets <[]Object>

DESCRIPTION:
     Secrets is the list of secrets allowed to be used by pods running using
     this ServiceAccount. More info:
     https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret

     ObjectReference contains enough information to let you inspect or modify
     the referred object.
```

You can learn more about the security implications of Kubernetes secrets in the [secret documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#restrictions).

Comment: Adding `secrets` to the service account with specific secret names (i.e. only read `user-service-secret` didn't stop the deployment from reading the other secrets (i.e. transaction-service-secret) with `valueFrom.secretKeyRef` and injecting them as environment variables to the pod

Answer (score 1):

> The idea is to restrict access to User-Service-Secret secret to User-Service service account that is assign to User-Service-Pod. So we can set this all up with the relevant Kubernetes resources (i.e. ServiceAccount, Role, RoleBinding), but we realize that **this may not be actually enforced**, because **Transaction-Service-Pod can just as easily read the User-Service-Secret secret** when Pod starts up, even though the service account its assign to doesn't have get permission to the User-Service-Secret.

Yes, this is correct.

This is documented for Kubernetes on [privilege escalation via pod creation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#privilege-escalation-via-pod-creation) - within a *namespace*.

> Users who have the ability to create pods in a namespace can potentially escalate their privileges within that namespace. They can create pods that access their privileges within that namespace. They can create pods that access secrets the user cannot themselves read, or that run under a service account with different/greater permissions.

To actually **enforce** this kind of Security Policies, you probably have to add an extra layer of policies via the *admission controller*. The [Open Policy Agent](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/kubernetes-introduction/) in the form of OPA Gatekeeper is most likely a good fit for this kind of policy enforcement.